# How to direct traffic to VM from host in xenserver?

Tags: centos7, xenserver, xencenter

Hi im farely new at this, please direct me to right direction, i've setup a xenserver and installed a centos 7 VM on the host. Host and VM have separate internal ip addresses. I can get to the host by typing the internal ip from a computer on the network from the browser but i cannot access the VM. 
My main goal is to host a website on the VM , but i am having problem accessing the VM.
if anybody could point me to the right direction i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it was a fire wall problem on the VM.

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones <- to get the zone argument.
firewall-cmd --zone=ZONE --add-service=http --permanent <- to activate the rule
```

you could substitute --add-service=http with --add-port=80/tcp

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215476/how-to-direct-hosts-browser-to-guest-vm